# Position an element under a div by using z-index

Tags: html, css, css-position, z-index

I tried to put a child div that will come under its parent and over the other elements.

```css
.box1{
  background-color: blue;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}

.box2{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 30%;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.box3{
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
  <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
<div class="box3"></div>
```

I want to position the red rectangle to be under the blue and over the yellow. I put the z-index on three of them. However, it doesn't work.

What do you think about this? Thanks!

***Update***: Although the boxes are in the right order, however, the elements inside those boxes cannot be clicked now.

You can take a look at the error here: https://jsfiddle.net/p1xd6zah/

Comment: The blue and the yellow box have different [stacking contexts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context). Since the blue box has a z-index of 3 and the yellow has a z-index of 1, the blue box and its children **will always be above the yellow**, regardless of the z-index of the inner children (you can set it to 1000 and it will not change anything). The only way to sandwich the red between the two is to make sure the red box is a sibling of the other two boxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a *hack* with `z-index`:

1. You can add `z-index: -1` to `box2`. (stacks the *child* below the *parent*)
2. Add `z-index: -2` and `position: relative` to `box3` (now stack this *behind* `box2`)

Remove the `z-index` from `box1` - see demo below:

```css
.box1 {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.box2 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 30%;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.box3 {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: -2;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
  <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
<div class="box3"></div>
```

Comment: Hi kukuz, there is another problem because the element inside the box cannot be clicked now. Could you please have a look at it? https://jsfiddle.net/p1xd6zah/

Comment: Thanks kukkuz, I will find another solution then.