# HTML DIV Stacking

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I working a layout that changes the behavior of z-index.

Is this possible?

The yellow box is a dropdown menu. It should be inside the Red box.

[image]

Comment: I think it will be easier it the yellow one will be the child of `div 2`

Comment: What have you implemented? This seems simple if you don't give any z-index to your `DIV 2`, then you can position `ELEMENT INSIDE DIV 1` using absolute/fixed positioning and place it above `DIV 2`.

Comment: I think this question has been asked too many times on StackOverflow already: did you try searching?

Comment: the yellow element is a dropdown menu from the header red.
but the design the div 2 is overlapping on the header

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Position an element under a div by using z-index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46200477/position-an-element-under-a-div-by-using-z-index)

Comment: @Terry yeah. they are using float. but i cannot add float on the dropdown.
and beside its not working

Comment: @Terry the your link it show the box 3 is not overlaps on the box 1.

Comment: Check out the answer below @Mark

Answer (score 0):

Here is all you need

```css
div {
height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.div1{
    background: #f00;
}
.div2{
top: 30px;
}
.div_child{
background: #3a2525;
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
    width: 50px;
    z-index: 1;
    }
```

```html
<div class="div1">
1
<div  class="div_child">
child
</div>
</div>
<div class="div2">
2


</div>
```

Comment: Hi, 

but the div_child should be inside the div1

Comment: The logic is same

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much anything is possible with CSS3. However the element inside div 1 would need to be separate for this to work. If it's inside div 1 it will drag div 1 around with it. You'll get much more flexibility if the side div is on it's own

But for your specific example you would need something like:

HTML:

```
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
<div class="side"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.top {
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    height: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    background: red;
}

.bottom {
    width: 90%;
    height: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    margin-left: 5%;
    background: grey;
    margin-top: -150px;
}

.side {
    width: 20%;
    height: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    margin-left: 78%;
    background: yellow;
    margin-top: -300px;
}
```

Working CodePen is here too: https://codepen.io/WebDevelopWolf/pen/mBLqxm

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this works, but it may be helpful for you:

```css
#div1, #div2{
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

#div1{
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

#div2{
  background-color: green;
}

#div2{
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: -300px;
  position: relative;
}

#div1 > div{
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  right: 0;
  top: 50px;
  z-index: 2;
}


.as-console-wrapper{ display: none !important;}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  DIV 1
  <div>INSIDE DIV 1</div>
</div>

<div id="div2">
  DIV 2
</div>
```